# How to run bash commands via pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to run bash commands on spark via Python.

My simple current code is as follows:

```
import subprocess

print("Test start")
subprocess.Popen("conda install numpy=1.15.2 -n python35env--yes", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
print("Test end")
```

The above code is getting executed successfully, and I do see both the print statement "Test start" and "Test end", but the `numpy` package is not getting installed in the python35env environment.

Am I missing anything important for running the conda install bash command in the Spark worker nodes? even on the driver node?

Comment: first : process = subprocess.Popen("conda install numpy=1.15.2 -n python35env--yes", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
second : output, error = process.communicate(), What do you get on 'error' var?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run it from the executable directory. By default subprocess run it from system.

```
subprocess.Popen("conda install numpy=1.15.2 -n python35env--yes", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd = 'your conda excutable path')
```

Comment: I have logged in to the VM and checked that `conda` command is available at system level. I mean I need not be in the conda installation directory, I can just type the conda command from anywhere in the terminal.

Comment: Try to add the logs of this command in a file and see what you get for eg.  conda install numpy=1.15.2 -n python35env--yes > log.txt

Answer (score 0):

Using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Example:

```
import subprocess    
result = subprocess.getoutput('<bash command>')
```